# Nginx Forward traffic from one URL to Another

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch cloud and I've been provided a long URL of kibana example.

```
https://5e765d3c21d84e8f8d6bd362d8bf6564.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243
```

I have configured the DNS routing in my Google Cloud DNS example:

```
https://example.com:9243
```

But when I open the URL i.e `example.com` it gives me "Unknown Deployment" error. The kibana is working fine on the long URL mentioned above, but somehow it is not routing to the short URL ie. `example.com` (Was working before but after upgrading to elasticsearch 7.0.0 it doesn't.)

So for that I want to configure Nginx proxy which will forward the traffic from the long URL to the short one. Please help me how to configure it.

Comment: What you are asking to do seems a bit ridiculous. What you are looking to do is setup a C name that will point `example.com` to `5e765d3c21d84e8f8d6bd362d8bf6564.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io`. That’s it. Nginx has nothing to do with this and if you add that on top of this it really overcomplicates a (relatively) simple issue.

Comment: I have already added a C name which points the long URL to example.com but it is still showing unknown deployment error in the example.com. I have mentioned that it was resolving properly before upgrading to elastic 7.0.0 but now it is not working.